# When i run my app for the second time it throws "program received signal exc_bad_access"

Tags: iphone, ios

when i rerun the program for the second time it crashes out...

```
- (IBAction)onConnect: (id)sender
{
    recordResults = NO;
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                            "<soap:Body>\n"
                            "<GetHotItems xmlns=\"http://www.mysite.com/WSMobileData/\" />\n"
                            "</soap:Body>\n"
                            "</soap:Envelope>\n"
                             ];

    NSLog( @"soapMessage: %@", soapMessage);

    // URL connection
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/WSMobileData/WSMobile.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];  

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://www.mysite.com/WSMobileData/GetHotItems" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"theRequest: %@", theRequest);

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"theXML: %@", theXML);
    [theXML release];

    if( xmlParser )
    {
        [xmlParser release];
    }

    xmlParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData] autorelease];
    [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [xmlParser parse];

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"GetHotItemsResult"])
    {
        if(!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
        recordResults = YES;
    }
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if( recordResults )
    {
        [soapResults appendString: string];
    }
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"GetHotItemsResult"])
    {
        recordResults = NO;
        NSLog(@"soapResults: %@", soapResults);
        [soapResults release];
        soapResults = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: what is your crash log ?

Comment: We need at least a crash log to answer. And please dont post your raw code, we are not supposed to do the investigation work for you. exc_bad_access means that you are realeasing an object too many times, check your autorelase and release lines with the debugger

Comment: @vdaubry: thank you.....the problem was in autorelease thank you so much...

Comment: @Satheesh if you think you got the problem, please add it as an answer..Not comment..And accept the answer..

Comment: Or better @vdaubry add your comment as answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need at least a crash log to answer. And please dont post your raw code, we are not supposed to do the investigation work for you. exc_bad_access means that you are realeasing an object too many times, check your autorelase and release lines with the debugger.

You could also use NSZombie to track down what object is released too many times.

This tutorial should help you :

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/

Hope this helps,
Vincent